# Paragraph Indent Together With Hanging Paragraphs :: Combining Commands

Tags: environments, paragraphs, combine

I think this is more an issue of my not understand Tex's syntax than anything else.  I want to format my paragraphs as shown below.  There seems to be a way of combining the three commands I'm using into a single statement but I can't quite work it out.  Grateful for any help anyone can offer...(though maybe I shouldn't be using {hangparas} in the first place; I don't know)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hanging}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{hangparas}{0.5cm}{1}
\setlength{\leftskip}{2cm}
\setlength{\rightskip}{2cm}

\lipsum[2]

\setlength{\rightskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}
\end{hangparas}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

James.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a list, it's easier. I left your original code for comparison.

Before the code, some explanations. In LaTeX almost all the specially formatted parts of text are obtained by means of a list: `center`, `quote`, `quotation` are all implemented as lists. This allows *nesting* lists in those special places, which `hanging` wouldn't allow, because lists use `\parshape` that overrides any value given to `\hangindent`.

All those special environments are “one item” lists. Any list must have an `\item` command at the start. The basic `list` environment doesn't define a label for the item, so we can just issue `\item\relax` and nothing would be printed, but LaTeX will be in the suitable state, respecting the given values to `\leftmargin`, `\rightmargin` and the other parameters. Why `\item\relax` and not `\item` only? Because `\item` looks for a possible optional argument; `\item[]` would be equivalent, but `\item\relax` is slightly more efficient.

Final note: it's better to use `\list` and `\endlist` rather than `\begin{list}` and `\end{list}`; in this way an error message about wrong closure (say you mistype `\end{beion}`) would refer to a not closed `bejon` environment rather than `list`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hanging} % remove this, it's just to show the output

\newenvironment{bejon}
  {\list{}{
     \itemindent=-.5cm
     \leftmargin=2.5cm
     \rightmargin=2cm
     \topsep=0pt
     \partopsep=0pt
   }\item\relax}
  {\endlist}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{hangparas}{0.5cm}{1}
\setlength{\leftskip}{2cm}
\setlength{\rightskip}{2cm}
\lipsum[2]
\setlength{\rightskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}
\end{hangparas}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{bejon}
\lipsum[2]
\end{bejon}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Possibly easier with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{bejon}
  {\itemize[
     label={},
     itemindent=-.5cm,
     leftmargin=2.5cm,
     rightmargin=2cm,
     nosep]
   \item\relax}
  {\enditemize}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{bejon}
\lipsum[2]
\end{bejon}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In `enumitem` style, use `\newlist{bejon}{itemize}{1} \setlist[bejon]{label={}, itemindent=-.5cm, leftmargin=2.5cm, rightmargin=2cm, nosep, before={\item\relax}}` instead of `\newenvironment{bejon}...`

Comment: @karlkoeller I don't find it much easier, but it's a good suggestion.

Comment: That looks perfect; thanks a bunch.  A quick question if you have a second though: would you mind talking me through what's actually going on here?  Within the environment, you're defining a "list"?  And everything you list in it gets triggered when you begin the environment?  The \relax then does what exactly?  just switches it off when you close the environment?

Comment: @JamesBejon I added some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The above responses were really helpful--so thanks.  But it turns out that what I thought I wanted wasn't what I wanted really after all.  What I'm after is something which causes each new line within a block of text to begin at a fixed left margin but to wrap around in an indented fashion.  Hopefully the example below makes this clear?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newenvironment{bejon}
  {\list{}{
     \itemindent=-.5cm
     \leftmargin=2.5cm
     \rightmargin=2cm
     \topsep=0pt
     \partopsep=0pt
   }\item\relax}
  {\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{bejon}
Here's a line which I want to be wrapped onto the next line but be indented in the same way that poems often are.  This works fine.
\end{bejon}
\begin{bejon}
Here's the next line.  Its left positioning is nice, but I don't like the way it skips a line
\end{bejon}
\begin{bejon}
The gaps between lines are too big.
\end{bejon}

\blindtext

\begin{bejon}
Here's an alternative \\
I like the way the next starts without a gap, but I don't want it indented. \\
\end{bejon}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the line gaps you mentioned, removing `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}` or just setting a new length before the section removes the gaps.